# how to convert soap response to object

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I have an xml file and a matching object definition.

How can i fill an instance of the object with the xml data?

---

I have registered to get ebay notification, and it sent me an xml in soap format.

How can i listen to this soap request and parse it into its matching object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to manipulate XML at all if this is a SOAP web service. See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!790.entry).

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(VS.71).aspx

> Serialization is the process of converting an object into a form that can be readily transported. For example, you can serialize an object and transport it over the Internet using HTTP between a client and a server. On the other end, deserialization reconstructs the object from the stream.
>
> **XML serialization serializes only the public fields and property values of an object into an XML stream**. XML serialization does not include type information. For example, if you have a Book object that exists in the Library namespace, there is no guarantee that it will be deserialized into an object of the same type.

Or, the more up to date version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=VS.100).aspx

Read the stuff on deserialisation.